# Configuring Rpi as a Privoxy-protected Access Point

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, software-installation

I am trying to configure my Rpi as a privoxy protected access point for all devices connected to it. I was successful in configuring the Rpi as a wifi access point and I successfully installed and ran the privoxy on the Rpi. When I access the net from the Pi itself (with Midori) the traffic is re-routed through the private proxy. However, none of the devices that are connected through the wifi access point get to connect to the proxy.

I was wondering if anyone can suggest some resources that would help me configure the Pi so that any device that connects to the wifi access point will automatically access the net through the Privoxy? Is this even possible? 
Thanks

Comment: You need to change the default route for the WiFi interface?

Answer (score 3):

Check this out- Raspberry PI as a TOR Relay. I believe this should be able to help you achieve  what you are looking for hopefully.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Tor-relay/step3/Network-configuration/

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure iptables to route the HTTP traffic to privoxy automatically.
Try adding these rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.1:8118
```

and

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8118
```

assuming wlan0 and eth0 are your network interfaces, 8118 is the port privoxy is listening to and 192.168.2.1 is your pi in the WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest to just set the Pi up running privoxy and then change your device proxy settings to point to the pi. You do not need the pi to be the wireless access point in this scenario.

I have a tutorial for doing exactly this here: http://c-mobberley.com/wordpress/index.php/2014/01/14/raspberry-pi-ad-blocking-proxy-installation-using-privoxy/